# Sending files via Bluetooth using command line

Tags: linux, command-line, raspberry-pi, bluetooth, buildroot

I am using buildroot to generate a custom linux image. I have the **bluez** packages installed, which allows me to connect to another device via bluetooth using the bluetoothctl command. However, when I use the **bt-obex** command to share a file  `bt-obex -p <macAddress> file`, I get the error  `Couldn't connect to DBus session bus: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY`   . I guess bt-obex doesn't use any GUI, so I don't understand the error.

Can bt-obex be used to work without GUI? Or do you now other way to share files via Bluetooth using the command line? Thank you.